# Change the name of multiple file upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Below is the function I have in my controller to help with the file name

```
public function pusher(Request $request){

    if($request->hasfile('doc')) {
        $files=$request->file('doc');
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $doc=new documents();
            $doc->claim_id=request('id');
            $doc->description=request('det');
            $doc->file_name=$name;
            $doc->type='received';
            $doc->cat=request('type');
            $doc->save();
            $location = 'Documents';
            $file->move($location,request('type')$name);
        }    
    }
    Alert::success('Successful', 'Document(s) Uploaded');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

My desired result is that I want the file to be uploaded with the following names e. if I have like 2 images uploaded, I would want the names to be doc1(1) and doc1(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use increments in foreach.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($files as $file){
   $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
   if (count($files) > 1) $name .= '(' . ++$i . ')';
   $doc=new documents();
   $doc->claim_id=request('id');
   $doc->description=request('det');
   $doc->file_name=$name;
   $doc->type='received';
   $doc->cat=request('type');
   $doc->save();
   $location = 'Documents';
   $file->move($location,request('type')$name);
}
```